# javascript google ocr text detection with php

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-vision

I'm new to Google Cloud Console. I have been able to create my API key and service account after which I downloaded a json file.

I'm currently working on a project that captures images on the website using a webcam and I wish to use the Google OCR to extract the text on the captured image. I tried making an ajax post request to the Goggle vision API URL:

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Bootstrap js-->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ui/loader-preview.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(function () {
       $(document).ready( function () {
          var options = {
 "requests": [
   {
     "image": {
       //"content": "<?php echo $src;?>",
      "source":{
        "imageUri":"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      },
     },
     "features": [
       {
         "type": "TEXT_DETECTION",
         "maxResults":1,
         "return":'text content',
         'rtype':'str'
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
};
         $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=MY_API_KEY',

           dataType:'JSON',
           data:JSON.stringify(options),
          // body:JSON.stringify(options),
           // data:options,
           // body:options,
           before: showLoader('Login in....'),
           success: function(response,status,xhr) {
               var msg=response;
             var p = $('<p></p>');
             var str = 'Response received <br />';
             var keys = [];
            for(var k in response) keys.push(k);

            alert("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
               str += response[k];

             p.html(str+status);

             $('body').append(p);
           },
           error: function(xhr,req,error) {
               hideLoader();
               var err =  xhr.responseText;
               var p = $('<p></p>');
               p.html("Error! "+err);
           $('body').append(p);
           },
             after: hideLoader()
         });
         return false;
       });
     });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

But I always receive this this error:

```
Error! { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\"}},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"TEXT_DETECTION\",\"maxResults\":1,\"return\":\"text content\",\"rtype\":\"str\"}]}]}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://www' could not be found in request message.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\"}},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"TEXT_DETECTION\",\"maxResults\":1,\"return\":\"text content\",\"rtype\":\"str\"}]}]}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageUri\":\"https://www' could not be found in request message." } ] } ] } }
```

I tried to change this portion of the code thus

```html
 dataType:'JSON',
           //data:JSON.stringify(options),
          // body:JSON.stringify(options),
            data:options,
            body:options,
```

And I get this error then:

```
Error! { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][image][source][imageUri]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][image][source][imageUri]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][maxResults]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][maxResults]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][return]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][return]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][rtype]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][rtype]' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][type]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][type]' could not be found in request message.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][image][source][imageUri]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][image][source][imageUri]' could not be found in request message." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][maxResults]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][maxResults]' could not be found in request message." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][return]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][return]' could not be found in request message." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][rtype]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][rtype]' could not be found in request message." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"requests[0][features][0][type]\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[0][features][0][type]' could not be found in request message." } ] } ] } }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check this library that wraps google vistion API https://github.com/jordikroon/Php-Google-Vision-Api maybe you can use this instead of using the API directly. Docs don't show the API key but there should be in php where user will not see it, like in tutorial that show code in node.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify that the data you are sending in your request is in JSON format:

```
// (...)
dataType: 'JSON',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(options),
// (...)
```

Also, note that you should remove the "return" and "rtype" keys from your feature or you’ll get another error.